# Storing an image path in a SQL database

Tags: android, sql, image

I have got an app that lets the user click on an image button. When clicked the user can chose an image from the gallery. 
Can someone give me an example of an SQL database storing the image path I receive in the onActivityResult method below?

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       if(requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
           Uri uri = data.getData();
           if(uri != null) {
              Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] {   
                                       android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA}, 
                                       null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0);             
                    cursor.close();

                    if(imageFilePath != null) {
                            // HERE I WANT TO STORE IT IN THE SQL DATABASE 
                        }
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: You really should accept some more answers... you've asked nine questions and accepted one answer.  People are not going to want to spend any time or effort if there is no reward for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [simple approach](http://pastebin.com/3pfzXMgv) and test my sample [SQLite database project](http://www.mediafire.com/?569on9rvb4qoa7w).

---

If you want to insert data then use:

```
 db.execSQL("INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES('"+imageFilePath+"');");
```

Where **db** is an object of   SQLiteDatabase type, you can find all the details in the sample.

---

You can also store image in database.Here are some good tutorials on saving **image** to database:

---

[Tutorial 1](http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com/2011/09/image-and-content-is-populated-from.html)

---

[Tutorial 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20200718180158/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/10/how-to-insert-image-data-to-sqlite.html)

---